# Where is this in Margaree Valley, Cape Breton Highlands, NS?

Tags: canada, identify-this, nova-scotia

I saw this picture on [Reddit](https://redd.it/75xdv8).  Can someone please pinpoint its location on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Margaree+Valley,+NS+B0E+2C0/@46.3445233,-61.0241704,12.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4b679eb87a9239b1:0xd464ec1d88c37819!8m2!3d46.35!4d-60.966667?hl=en)? I'd like to drive to it when I visit. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following image appears to be the likely location (from Google Earth). The corresponding Google Maps location is https://goo.gl/maps/9yM1MCiv2zkzNENx7

[image]